# Contar sequência e distância de números em um array

Tags: php

Tenho um array e com ele preciso contar a **sequência** e **distância** entre os números.

```
$a = array(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 39);
```

Notem que há 6 blocos de sequências numéricas em `$a`:

1. **1 - 2**
2. **8 - 9 - 10**
3. **15 - 16 - 17**
4. **20 - 21**
5. **23 - 24**
6. **26 - 27 - 28 - 29**

E com a **maior** distância entre os números de 7 dezenas (há 7 números entre 31 e 39):

31 - **32** - **33** - **34** - **35** - **36** - **37** - **38** - 39

Como posso obter esses resultados?

Tentei alguns códigos, mas acho que minha lógica está incorreta.

Comment: O_O..não entendi essa lógica :)

Comment: O que não entendeu? Rs, está bem explicado. Quero saber quantas sequências existem (no meu exemplo seriam 6 sequências) e preciso saber a MAIOR distância que existe entre os números dentro do array (no meu exemplo 7).

Comment: Desculpe, mas parece aqueles problemas da revista Super Interessante. Pra mim não ficou claro nem um pouco. Desculpe a ironia mas não entendi nada. rs.. Se algum outro amigo entender poderá te ajudar.

Comment: Também entendi patavinas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para achar a menor distancia entre cada numero precisa apenas de comparar o numero em que vai com o da frente, e se for maior que a distancia calculada até ao momento, atualiza-a.

As sequências já envolvem mais complexidade, mas pode descobri-las vendo se a distancia ao elemento da frente é `1` e caso seja adiciona esse elemento a um array, que por sua vez é adicionado a outro array global de sequencias. O termino da sequência corrente dá-se quando a distancia voltar a deixar de ser `1`.

Exemplo de implementação desta lógica:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 39);

$maiorDistancia = 0;
$sequencias = [];
$ultimaSeq = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($a)-1; ++$i){
    $dist = abs($a[$i]-$a[$i+1]); //distancia entre este e o proximo

    if ($dist > $maiorDistancia) $maiorDistancia = $dist; //se maior atualiza

    if (($a[$i+1]-$a[$i]) == 1){ //teste para sequencia
        if (isset($sequencias[$ultimaSeq])){
            $sequencias[$ultimaSeq][] = $a[$i+1]; //se ja existe uma sequencia acrescente
        }
        else { //se é uma nova insere os 2 primeiros elementos
            $sequencias[$ultimaSeq][0] = $a[$i];
            $sequencias[$ultimaSeq][1] = $a[$i+1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $ultimaSeq++;
    }
}
```

Saida:

```
Maior distancia: 8 
 Sequencias: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 10
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 17
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 21
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => 24
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26
            [1] => 27
            [2] => 28
            [3] => 29
        )

)
```

[Ideone com esta solução](https://ideone.com/zyU76r)

Notas:

- A solução apenas assume sequencias crescentes, pelo que se for possível ter sequencias decrescentes torna-se necessário fazer alguns ajustes no código.
- A distancia utilizada foi calculada com base na função [`abs`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.abs.php), e por isso tanto contempla distancias positivas como negativas.
- A distancia entre `39` e `31` é mesmo `8`, algo que a calculadora pode comprovar, mas se quiser obter os `7` porque quer desconsiderar o próprio `39` apenas precisa de subtrair `1`.

Comment: Perfeito @Isac, exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Só uma observação, tive que utilizar `array_values()` em meu array que vinha de uma consulta SQL pois estava retornando valores nada compatíveis com a realidade. Obrigado!

Comment: P.S: Após a utilização do `array_values()` a distância ficou ok, porém a sequência bagunçou tudo. Por exemplo, onde o valor correto seria 4, retornou 8. Onde era 5, retornou 7. Sabe informar o porque?

Comment: @thiago porque o `array_values` ? Apenas as sequencias interessam e não as suas posições. Para percorrer deve utilizar um `foreach` e não um `for` que resolve o problema. Exemplo: `foreach ($sequencias as $seq) {`

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que o array está ordenado, e que você só precisa saber o número de sequencias e a MAIOR distancia entre os números (entendi isso).

Basta percorrer a array, olhando dois numeros consecutivos e armazenando os valores.
Pode fazer assim (fiz num estilo mais python, não manjo de php, mas a pergunta é bem independente de linguagem):

```
i=0
MAIOR_DIST = 0
IN_SEQUENCIA = false
SEQUENCIAS = 0
last = null
for elemento in array:
    if last==null:
        last = elemento
        continue
    if elemento - last > 1: //nao e sequencia
        if IN_SEQUENCIA:
            SEQUENCIAS += 1 //significa que terminou uma sequencia
        IN_SEQUENCIA=false
        if elemento - last > MAIOR_DIST://se for maior que a ultima maior distancia, atualiza
            MAIOR_DIST=elemento-last
    else:
        IN_SEQUENCIA=1

 print SEQUENCIAS, MAIOR_DIST
```